# ActiveMQ Queue And consumers

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am having a scenerio that , i am having more than 4 clients and i want to send a single queue messages to all of that clients. I didnt acknowledge for the client side. So anyone can get that messages from the queue. But the case is that i want to know the number of consumers who consumed that message. Can anyone help me to get the consumer count.

Here below is code that i wrote.

```
  public static boolean sendMessage(String messageText)
  { 
    try {     
      StompConnection connection = new StompConnection(); 
      HashMap<String, String> header = new HashMap<String, String>();
      header.put(PERSISTENT, "true");
      connection.open(URLhost, port); 
      connection.connect("", ""); 
      connection.begin("MQClient");
      Thread.sleep(100);
      connection.send(queuePath, messageText, "MQClient", header); 
      connection.commit("MQClient");                
      connection.disconnect(); 
      return true;
    } catch (Exception e) { 
         throw new BasicException(AppLocal.getIntString("ActiveMQ service ERROR"), e);
    } 
  } 

  public static String receiveMessage() {
      try {
      StompConnection connection = new StompConnection(); 
      connection.open(URLhost, port); 
      connection.connect("", ""); 
      connection.subscribe(queuePath, Subscribe.AckModeValues.INDIVIDUAL); 
      connection.begin("MQClient");
      Thread.sleep(1000);//below not a good NO DATA test .. worked by making thread sleep a while
      if (connection.getStompSocket().getInputStream().available() > 1) 
      {
          StompFrame message = connection.receive(); 
          connection.commit("MQClient");
          connection.disconnect();
          return message.getBody();
      }
      else
          return "";

      } catch (Exception e) { 
          e.printStackTrace(); 
      }
      return "";
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing to a Queue, then exactly one consumer will receive the message. The whole goal of point-to-point messaging is that only one of the consumers will receive the message.

If you want to send a message and have it be received by all of the consumers, then you'd want to use a Topic instead of a Queue.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to a topic, multiple clients can consume that same message.

You can probably figure out how many consumed your message by subscribing to the [ActiveMQ.Advisory.MessageConsumed.Topic](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html)

Comment: Is that possible to have each client acknoledgement while using a topic message.  Also how can it be possible to send a message in topic using StompConnection?

Comment: send to /topic/sometopicname

Comment: Thanks for the help. Also i have the situation that once a single client acknowledge, its removed from the queue itself. Is the same happens when i use topic?

Comment: You should probably read up on the semantics of messaging (queus/topics) a bit to get the concepts, but yes. The queue is a transport mechanism only. If you are really concerned about acknowledements from the receiver to the sender, I would recommend that you require each consumer to send back a message with an ACK to a specific reply queue for that matter. Here is a nice series of blog articles on the STOMP/AMQ matter: http://www.devco.net/archives/2011/12/11/common-messaging-patterns-using-stomp.php